# Best way to make multiple concurrent calls to single wcf service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, client

I making a windows app that has to process a lot of data (6MM records or more) calling a WCF service.

For this i'm using a Parallel.Foreach to make multiple conections to the Service.

I had the following in my app.config to allow multiple connections to the server:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

First, I tried with the following code:

```
Parallel.ForEach<ItemType>(list, (item, loopState) =>
{
    ServiceAClient client = new ServiceAClient();
    var data = GetDataFromDB(item);
    client.Process(data);
});
```

With the code above, about 40 to 50 items where processed per second, that was fine, but the memory kept going up until it took all the system memory and blocked the app.

So, I tried calling the Garbage Collector after a while using a timer (45 secs). With this the memory usage decreased after the GC.Collect() gets called, but not fast enough. I thought to call the GC more frequently but I know is not a good idea, and could overhead the application in

So, I changed the code to dispose the client, to look like this

```
Parallel.ForEach<ItemType>(list, (item, loopState) =>
    {
        using(ServiceAClient client = new ServiceAClient())
        {
             var data = GetDataFromDB(item);
             client.Process(data);
        }
    });
```

At the begging everything worked fine and memory didn't start to increase and kept at the same level, so far so good, but after a while (several minutes or couple of hours) everything started to go really slow and only procesed one item per second but the memory usage remained low.

What is it happening? Is the overhead of closing the channel making it go slower? Should I use a single client to make all calls to the service? That would limit the number of connections to the service?

Comment: Did you try to you only one static `client`? Did you investigate your memory with profiler?

Comment: That was part of the question. If I should use a single client for all request, but I don't know if this will reduce the number of active connections to the server. I do investigate the memory with a profiler, that`s how I realized that the clients were the objects that were consuming the memory.

Comment: You should explicitly call Close/Abort on the client, before Dispose (as Close could throw). See details here: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15941/TIP-Closing-your-WCF-Connections-properly.htm